# E0624 when trying to use private methods in a private module in Rust

Tags: rust

Let's say I have this module `foo` with an internal public struct `Bar`
now, `Bar` has some functions that should be private, Let's say they're fairly low-level functions that are required to build out some of the bigger, public functions.

let's say we have the following file structure

```
src/
├─ foo/
│  ├─ private_module.rs // private module with private functions
├─ foo.rs
├─ lib.rs // Public API
```

within `crate::foo::private_module` we have the following

```rs
impl Bar {
    fn my_private_function() -> () {}
}
```

and within `crate::foo` we have the following

```rs
mod private_module;

struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    pub fn my_public_function(&self) -> () {
        self.my_private_function() // E0624! private associated function
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to do this? The only way to get around it is to make these private functions public, which will expose them in the public API of this struct despite the impl block living in a private module!

Should I have the low-level private functions at the root of the module and higher-level public functions in their own submodules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Visibility and Privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html) docs has a number of different visibility levels you can use, such as `pub(super)` to only expose items to its parent module.

```
struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    pub(super) fn my_private_function() -> () {}
}
```